# CreateSqlQuery on entity with formula property

Tags: nhibernate

When I try to query a table using CreateSqlQuery  and convert it to an entity containing formula property, I get the below Adoexception.

"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldName"

In the first place is it possible to use the createsqlquery on entity that has formula mapping ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to use `CreateSQLQuery` with formulas.

Here's a proof of concept. Mapping (class is not hard to guess):

```
<class name="Foo">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="hilo"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Data"/>
  <property name="DataX2" formula="Data * 2"/>
</class>
```

And here's a query:

```
var foos = session.CreateSQLQuery(
                   @"
                   select Id          as {foo.Id},
                          Data        as {foo.Data},
                          Data + Data as {foo.Data2}
                   from   Foo
                   ")
                  .AddEntity("foo", typeof(Foo))
                  .List<Foo>();
```

If you look closely, you'll see that I'm using a different formula than the one declared in the mapping. NHibernate allows anything as long as all the properties are in the query.

I suggest that you read [17.1.2. Entity queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html#d0e11311) and the following points.

Comment: Your solution here seems to only be a work around to a real bug that exists.

Comment: @GaryB if you think there's a bug, feel free to open an issue in the tracker, making sure to include a failing unit test,

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not familiar with the relationship between Nhibernate and Hibernate issue tracking. I'm stating it is a bug because it has been declared one within Hibernate but apparently not within Nhibernate so it is not entirely fair for me to call it one regarding Nhibernate. At this point I'm happy with the alias solution therefore I don't find it in my interest to create an Nhibernate issue.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I found the following

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-6571

Seems this is a real bug in hibernate that they've decided not to fix.  There are some workarounds.  I think the best is to use aliases for property names. Aliases must be used as documented here:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-aliasreferences